# NGINX, forwarding few localhosts to php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx

I've stuck on simple thing, please help.
I have 2 directories with PHP projects: /var/www/api/ and /var/www/api-beta/.
I want to forwarding each of them to PHP-FPM.
Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    set $doc_root /var/www/api;
    root $doc_root;
    index  index.php index.html;


  location /beta {
            alias /var/www/api-beta;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        set $php_root /var/www/api;
        if ($request_uri ~* /beta) {
             set $php_root /var/www/api-beta;
              }

            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;


    }
}
```

I've tried do this with `if ($request_uri ~* /beta)` but it didn't work. I think problem this, because project from /var/www/api works fine, but from /var/www/api-beta I have "File not found." error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be simpler to create a `location` block for each PHP root:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root /var/www/api;
    index  index.php index.html;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ^~ /beta {
        alias /var/www/api-beta;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- avoid using alias and try_files together. See [this long standing issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).
- the `^~` modifier cause the prefix location to take precedence over the regular expression location above. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

Comment: It works, thanx! I thought, that we can use same directive location for PHP.