# Nginx Yii2 configuration in different folders

Tags: nginx, configuration-files, yii2-basic-app, nginx-location

I faced with problem in configuring nginx server for yii2 basic app.

Here is my service block file :

```
server {
    listen       80 ;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-server.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error-server.log;

    charset utf-8;

    location  /fetch {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html/another_folder/web/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

         location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

}
```

My project located in another folder "another_folder".
And i want that when user goes to url : http://ip/fetch files nginx will serve files from another folder.

My error log file returns me :

```
2017/02/11 12:38:52 [error] 4242#0: *12 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.php (No such file or directory)" while reading response header from upstream
```

And brother shows :
No input file specified.

Can you give help me with this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want `/fetch/index.php` to be located at `/usr/share/nginx/html/another_folder/web/index.php` or `/usr/share/nginx/html/another_folder/web/fetch/index.php`?

Comment: In this folder :/usr/share/nginx/html/another_folder/web/index.php

Comment: You need to use an `alias` directive. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137658/nginx-forwarding-few-localhosts-to-php-fpm/42138410#42138410).

Comment: Thank you. It resolved problem. But it cant find urls using pretty Url in yii2. it again looks index.php file in /usr/share/nginx/html folder

Comment: Is this within the `another_folder` root? And will the pretty URIs be prefixed with `/fetch`?

Comment: Yes. Correct. Sorry for long response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Further to your comment, any URI beginning with `/fetch` that does not match a static file within the aliased path, should be redirected to `/fetch/index.php`.

```
location ^~ /fetch {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/another_folder/web;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /fetch/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

We avoid using `try_files` with `alias` because of [this long term issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) regarding the use of `if`.