# Nginx configuaration for wordpress under different path

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, symfony

I have php website (symfony framework running in dev env) under example.com and wordpress blog under example.com/blog/ .

Now I'm trying make make wordpress working under this set up.
As of right now I have only static files served by nginx.
I can't make php files executed.

Symfony app root dir: /data/example.com 
Wordpress root dir: /data/example.com-blog/web

My nginx config

```
  server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;

    charset utf-8;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com_error.log;

    root /data/example.com/web/;
    index  app_dev.php;
    error_page   400 401 404 500  = /index.php;

    location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
    }

    location ^~ /blog {
            log_not_found   on;
            access_log      on;

            root /data/example.com-blog/web;
            rewrite ^/blog/([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ /$1 break;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php$is_args$args;

            location ~ \.php {
                    return 401; # for
            }
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    }

location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm.socket;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  HTTPS off;
            include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|js|css|htm|html|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|flv|htc|xsl|eot|woff|ttf|svg)$ {
            expires 1w;
            tcp_nodelay off;
    }
  }
```

I tried to use RichardSmith's example and now I'm getting 403 error

```
location ^~ /blog {
alias /data/example.com-blog/web;

if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /blog/index.php last; }

location ~ \.php$ {
    if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm.socket;
}
}
```

Comment: You need a similar configuration to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176020/nginx-yii2-configuration-in-different-folders/42203734#42203734).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nginx Yii2 configuration in different folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176020/nginx-yii2-configuration-in-different-folders)

Comment: @RichardSmith I tried your example and now I getting 403 error  (in nginx log directory index of ... is forbidden)

Comment: You have a strange value for your `index` directive. You may need to set `index index.php;` inside the `location ^~ /blog` block to override the inherited value.