# Nginx Wordpress Subdirectory - Hiding Subdirectory Folders

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, nginx-location

I'm attempting to serve a wordpress blog from my laravel App, however the actual wordpress build is nested a few levels deep within the site root and I need to exclude certain folders from the URI.

Specifically, the wordpress build resides in `root_folder/wordpress/wp_build`, which needs to be be served via `example.com/blog`.

My current attempt at an Nginx config allows me to access the wordpress site at `example.com/blog`, however I'm unable to access the WP dashboard or even the build's login page.

Here is the relevant portion of my nginx config

```
server_name example.com;
root /home/user/laravel_app/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {
    autoindex off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location ~ ^/blog {
    root /home/user/laravel_app/public/wordpress/wordpress_build;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/wordpress_build/index.php?args;
}

#### PHP Setup ####
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Additional details

- Url `example.com/blog/wp-admin` incorrectly redirects to `example.com/blog/wp-admin/
- Clicking on posts works as it should
- Both `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` are currently set to `example.com/wordpress/wordpress_build`. Setting either to `example.com/blog` seems to break wordpress functionality altogether.

Comment: Try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176020/nginx-yii2-configuration-in-different-folders/42203734#42203734) using `alias` with a nested PHP location.

Comment: @RichardSmith Works perfectly - I cannot thank you enough! When I tried using alias previously I was beginning from the public root (not including `/home/user`). You are a saint