# Nginx working with apache-like locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am trying to migrate my personal sterver from apache to nginx, but i cant get the location to work.

My server have several apps, avaliable in some /something from root, like url.com/git url.com/mediaWiki, url.com/vnstat url.com/redmine

In apache a have a bunch of config files for each app:

redmine.conf

```
<Location "/redmine">
    Options none
    Require all granted

    PassengerEnabled On
    RailsBaseURI /redmine
    RailsEnv production
</Location>
```

vnstat_php.conf

```
Alias /vnstat /var/www/vnstat_php

<Directory /var/www/vnstat_php>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

I am trying to replicate this on nginx, but my best try so far end up with a weird url. I only manage the thing to work writing on the main ngix config file:

```
server {
    listen       8123 default_server;
    listen       [::]:8123 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /var/www/html;

    location / {
    }

    location /vnstat/ {
        root   /var/www/vnstat_php/;
        index  index.php;
    }
}
```

The root page is working ok, but the /vnstat link send me to

```
2017/02/20 11:37:19 [error] 27538#0: *1 "/var/www/vnstat_php/vnstat/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 177.92.59.216, server: _, request: "GET /vnstat/ HTTP/1.1", host: "url.com:8123"
```

It is looking for a vnstat directory inside /var/www/vnstat_php/ instead using it as root. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You need `alias` not `root`. Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176020/nginx-yii2-configuration-in-different-folders/42203734#42203734) perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

As described at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

> A path to the file is constructed by merely adding a URI to the value of the root directive. If a URI has to be modified, the alias directive should be used.

you should use alias for this case:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

```
location /vnstat/ {
  alias /var/www/vnstat_php/;
}
```

But using PHP with nginx you should consider to work with FastCGI: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/phpfcgi/

Comment: Still looking in the wrong place
 open() "/var/www/html/vnstat" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 177.92.59.216, server: _, request: "GET /vnstat HTTP/1.1", host: "url.com:8123", referrer: "http://url.com:8123/frame.html"