# Two document roots with nginx and fastcgi

Tags: php, angularjs, nginx, fastcgi

I am using nginx and php in a docker-environment, which works fine for a single application. Now I want to develop an application based in yii2/php as backend and angular as frontend, so I need one webserver serving the client, and another one serving the API backend. The directory structure looks as follows:

```
/var/www/html/ $ tree -L 3
.
├── client
│   ├── dist
│   │   ├── 0.chunk.js
│   │   ├── 0.chunk.js.map
│   │   ├── assets
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── e2e
│   │   ├── ...
│   ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── ...
├── docker
│   ├── mysql
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   └── my.cnf
│   ├── nginx
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   └── default.conf
│   └── php7
│       └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
└── server
    ├── api
    │   ├── common
    │   ├── config
    │   ├── modules
    │   └── web
    │   │   └── index.php 
    ├── common
    ├── composer.json
    ├── console
    └── vendor
```

The frontend application is located in `/var/www/html/client/dist/, the nginx config looks as follows:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/client/dist/;
    index index.html index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
            # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
        }

    location /api {
        root /var/www/html/server/api/web/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Using this config, the frontend works (URL: /), however the API does not. What I need is:

Request "/": serve the angular app from `/var/www/html/client/dist/`
Request "/api": use `index.php` from `/var/www/html/server/api/web/`

How to configure this? Thank you.

//Edit: New configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html/client/dist/;
    index index.html;

    charset utf-8;

    location ~ ^/api(.*) {
        alias /var/www/html/server/api/web/;

        # Redirect everything that isn't a real file to index.php
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$1$args;
        index index.php;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass php:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
            fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
            fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
            fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
        }
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    access_log off;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log error;

    sendfile off;

    client_max_body_size 100m;
}
```

Calling http://localhost/api/v1/users should be redirected to /var/www/html/server/api/web/index.php with v1/users as parameter (or however Yii2 handles the pretty URLs), but returns a 404 not found instead.

Error Log shows this message, so it looks like the alias directive is not taking effect:

```
2017/07/11 16:51:57 [error] 5#5: *1 open() "/var/www/html/client/dist/index.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /api/v1/users HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Comment: Cant you just create 2 Virtual Hosts to do this

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm not too familiar with nginx, coming from Apache. Is it possible to have two virtual hosts listening for the same domain?

Comment: Sorry neither am I, but [I can use Google](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/) Apparently they are called Server Blocks in nginx

Comment: Yes, but in this case I need a different domain (or subdomain) which is not what I want. Frontend should be reachable via `domain.tld`, the API using `domain.tld/api`.

Comment: I think you need to use an [`alias` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42137658/nginx-forwarding-few-localhosts-to-php-fpm/42138410#42138410).

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you. Tried as suggested and came up with the edited nginx config. Returns a 404 however. When using the directory as document root directly, the API in general works (without the /api) in the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you need to rewrite the pretty URIs to, but you need to use the URI of `index.php` which includes the `/api` prefix.

The [`alias` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) works best with a [prefix `location`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location), otherwise you will need to construct the path with captured variables.

For example:

```
location ^~ /api/ {
    alias /var/www/html/server/api/web/;

    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) { 
        rewrite ^/api(.*) /api/index.php?uri=$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much. This is working right out of the box with Yii2 and PrettyURLs enabled. API access now works and frontend is not affected.